# 14.04 Chinese Ibus Input - No Options

Tags: language-support, ibus, pinyin

getting my new 14.04 rig going ;-) Pretty happy with it, everything seems to be working great.

For Chinese input, however, having a problem. I went through the typical steps, open language in settings, let it install some stuff, then add Chinese and choose Ibus. Then, after logging in and out, I see the language icon in my system tray.

However, when I go to add the Chinese into Ibus, it only lets me choose "Chinese", which isn't an input method. It should give me a bunch of choices like pinyin, bopomo or whatever, I only use pinyin so don't know those names.

I saw someone online had a little command which helped people with similar problems, but it did not work for me, even after a re-start.

So, anyone got a solution?

Edit: Here is what it looks like, just "Chinese" in the list, when there should be a bunch of input options like pinyin, potomofo, and so on.
[image: No options for input method]

Comment: Which Ubuntu distro are you on? Especially if you are on standard Ubuntu, you may want to read https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I am on 14.04 64 bit, standard. Its weird because ibus-pinyin is installed, but I don't get the option.

Comment: I tried some commands with Ibus and am getting weird results. Ibus restart doesn't make the indicator disappear at all. That indicator is just a standard one, where is the Ibus settings?  Then, I tried ibus engine and it said no engine started...then I tried ibus list-engine and it said can't connect to ibus...I don't think ibus is running...

Comment: ibus address returns (null)...I feel so stupid now what am I missing.

Comment: Sigh...I am having the same problem...

Comment: Okay, from a Chinese forum, one solution works for me. The problem persists when you use GNOME classic, switch back to Unity, and then you can see all the option this time.

Comment: Yeah it never occurred to me that using the gnome-fallback package would interfere with the dialog. I am on Mint 17 now, and its no problem to set up at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1.** I think you need to open Language Support and install Chinese(simplifed or traditional)

**2.** You can try to install Chinese input method manually

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-pinyin 
sudo apt-get install ibus-sunpinyin
```

**3.** Restart IBus daemon

```
ibus restart
```

**4.** Then you can find Chinese(pinyin) input method in Text Entry Setting.
[image]

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks to both of you in advance. Ok both of you are talking about Text Entry Settings, and maybe I am being dense, but the picture I provide above *is* the Text Entry Settings. I can put Chinese in there, but it is *just* Chinese, no input method like pinyin or anything. I have installed Chinese in languages, then I go to Text Entry...and add Chinese...and then nothing, no entry. Only Ibus itself is asking me what type of Chinese entry I want to use. Still, I guess I am doing something wrong, Ibus isn't working right.

Comment: So, you say I will have pinyin there in Text Entry, (and I am glad for the confirmation about that), but for some reason, I don't. See picture above pls.

Comment: @RhZ: Ok, now I see. Indeed the installed IM engines should appear there. Even if it should be sufficient to log out and re-login after installing an engine, have you tried to reboot?

Comment: Ok I think its getting better. Before, I was missing the engine entirely, now I have an engine with a million different options. However, when I go to choose, its still not there.

Comment: I tried uninstalling Chinese and restarting, then I checked, the engine had 3 options, but when I re-installed now the options are only 2 (google which I had downloaded and sun), but not the regular pinyin. So it changed when I installed Chinese. I think this may be because I am in China, it recognized my locale and gave me Chinese automatically...I wish they would just stop messing with people. If I wanted a localized system I would have asked for it...

Comment: Yeah this is a broader issue. Every option in my Ibus engine is ok to choose except Chinese. I have to purge the Chinese from my system first I guess. I may reinstall. Thanks again for the support!

Comment: @RhZ Sorry, I don't have enough reputation score to attach a picture for you. You should search "pinyin" in your Ubuntu Software Center, you can find an ibus input method and check it if installed. I think it is the key for your problem. I installed Ubuntu in English language, later install Chinese language and select Chinese language input method in ibus.

Comment: Ok Gino I will try. I had a break as this is a little frustrating. But overall I am very happy with 14.04, once I get rid of Unity which I dislike. Thanks!

Comment: I think OP most likely has solved the issue. Just to add a note here for those who were having the same problem: You'll have to log out/restart after you've installed the input methods. They won't appear in the same session after installation.

Answer (score 8):

Got it! I am so stupid haha...

Just run `ibus-setup`, that will get ibus going and you can choose your input method.

So simple...and I will never get that hour back ;-)

But it does seem buggy to be honest.

Comment: It sounds to me as if you have missed that you are supposed to use `System Settings -> Text Entry` instead of ibus-setup. Did you read the document I linked to?

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I replied above to Gino. That pic I put in the question is Text Entry. I have Chinese there, but no specific input.

Answer (score 1):

Once the Ibus-Pinyin installed, the `ibus-setup` is not even necessary, just chose in the language list "Chinese Pinyin" instead of "Chinese". Once installed, you can configure it easily from language choice list or from the Pinyin icon.

I wasted a lot of time on this question, I hope you'll get it quickly.

Comment: yes you are right. But I think I ran into a bug. But its all good now