# How can I delete useless text entry in the drop down menu?

Tags: keyboard, chinese

In order to type Chinese in Ubuntu, I tried the method described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/667307).

In short, what I did was typing two lines in terminal, which are:

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-libpinyin
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources | sed "s/]/, ('ibus', 'libpinyin')]/")"
```

And then I found it didn't work for me, so I uninstall the package by this:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove ibus-libpinyin
```

However, the text entry menu looks like this:

[image]

How can I delete these two gray items 'libpinyin' in the drop down menu?
I couldn't find them in keyboard--textentry

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too. I tried the following steps:

1. List item
2. run `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`
3. go to *System Settings* and click *Text Entry*.
4. add input source you need back.

Everything went back to normal!

Comment: OP wants to *delete* input sources, not *add* them.

Comment: I think they meant that **all** the sources will be deleted, not just the ones you want to delete, so you need to add back in any you didn't mean to delete.