# How to add chinese input system in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: keyboard, ibus, input

I've been using ubuntu operating system for a long time from ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu 20.04. I recently had to reinstall the operating system from scratch because I had a problem and could not find the solution, at first everything was fine until when I got into the configuration of the keyboard input methods to add pinyin and Chinese to type in That language I realized that I do not get suggestions for words in Chinese as before. Do you know how to solve the problem? Although I have been using Ubuntu for some time, I do not consider myself an expert, so I would like you to explain it to me in a clear way to be able to solve it well without making any mistakes,thanks

Answer (score 3):

I tried https://www.pinyinjoe.com/linux/ubuntu-18-gnome-chinese-setup.htm and it works on my Ubuntu 22.04(I have just upgraded from 20.04 and hope this could help through the version is not the same).

Also before this I tried some solutions in [How do I get Chinese input to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59356/how-do-i-get-chinese-input-to-work) and have installed some inputs (including Chinese, Hanyu Pinyin). I am able to toggle the different inputs, but thing did not work. The top-right bar shows `zh` instead of `en` which means the input has been toggled. But when I type the what happens is totally the same with English input.

For me things get working after I log out and re-login. And Chinese(Intelligent Pinyin) appear in keyboard choices. This input works for me.

Comment: What about later when the links do not work? It is ok to have links if the important info is ALSO in the body of the answer. Having said that 22.04 is not out and therefore off topic on this site and not an answer at all at this time.

Comment: @David while questions about problems using 22.04 are off topic, I see no reason to disallow answers that mention upgrading to it solved a problem.

Comment: This is important: “log out and re-login"