# Can't type Japanese or Chinese on Ubuntu 20.04 with Ibus or Fcitx

Tags: ibus, japanese, fcitx, mozc

Ever since installing Ubuntu 20.04 I've had trouble typing Japanese or Chinese.

I've installed Japanese and Chinese languages under "Region & Language" and I've set the input method to Ibus. I've also chosen Mozc and "intellient pinyin" as input sources along with English.

Despite this, I can't type anything, it just comes out as regular English. I tried testing out some European languages and they can type the special characters just fine.

I used to have fcitx but stopped using it since it also would not type anything (but it would type Japanese) other than English.

Comment: You will need to provide a bit more information.  Did you try changing to a Japanese keyboard?  After you do that, you also need to change to "Hiragana".  Was this option available to you?

Comment: Ah, sorry.

Yes, I believe so. The input icon in the top right of screen says "あ" It is set to hiragana.

Comment: If you've switched to that, you should be able to type fine...  I have to admit sometimes I put my focus on a window and then it reverts back to "A".  Then I have to switch back.  I don't know why that occurs.  But seems like it's ok for you?  I don't type Chinese, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: I was looking around and did a "env | grep -E 'XMOD|_IM'" command and it said this:
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
QT4_IM_MODULE=fcitx
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=fcitx
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
GTK_IM_MODULE_FILE=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodul

So some things, including qt4, are still set to fcitx? How do I change this?
@Ray

Comment: I don't know...  Perhaps [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260601/understanding-setting-up-different-input-methods) might help?  I guess you need to uninstall `fcitx`, etc. completely or something?  I can't tell where they are set.  For me, they are set to `uim`.

Comment: Try this. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294480/how-to-add-chinese-input-system-in-ubuntu-20-04/1294525#1294525

Comment: Hey guys,
I ending up fixing it! Apparently I had no .xprofile in my $/home. I went ahead and made one and wa-la, it's working!